# Erro ao trabalhar com formatação de data no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estou com uma certa dificuldade para manipular um **input** do tipo **date**. Ao utilizar este tipo de input a data é formatada como Y-m-d, porém, em meu form quero digitar dd/mm/yyyy.

Model User:

```
//...
protected $dates = [
    'data_nascimento'
];
```

Input (blade):

```
<input id="data_nascimento" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('data_nascimento') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="data_nascimento" value="{{ $usuario->data_nascimento->format('d/m/Y') or old('data_nascimento') }}">
```

Erro:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

Solução (ao invés de aplicar o format no input realizei direto no controller e passei para a view):

```
$usuario->data_nascimento = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $usuario->data_nascimento)->format('d/m/Y');

return view('user-profile.edit', compact('usuario'));
```

Já quando vou gravar a data no banco faço somente uma inversão de parâmetros:

```
$request->merge(
    ['data_nascimento' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->data_nascimento)->format('Y-m-d')]
);
```

Mas me sinto como se estivesse utilizando um paliativo, ao invés da solução definitiva/correta.

Obs: existem casos onde data_nascimento retorna null

Answer (score 1):

Laravel está a fazer internamente o [seguinte](https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator):

```
isset($usuario->data_nascimento->format('d/m/Y')) ? $usuario->data_nascimento->format('d/m/Y') : old('data_nascimento');
```

Caso [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) retorne false ("***Returns the formatted date string on success or FALSE on failure.***"), ou `old('data_nascimento')` for `null`, esse erro é mostrado: [DOCS `old`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input) ("***If no old input exists for the given field,  null will be returned:***").
[Exemplo do erro](https://ideone.com/I7sXvw) (ambos os casos, `isset(false)` ou `isset(null)` fazem *trigger* a esse erro)

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
<input id="data_nascimento" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('data_nascimento') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="data_nascimento" value="{{!is_null(old('data_nascimento')) ? old('data_nascimento') : $usuario->data_nascimento->format('d/m/Y')}}">
```

OU:

```
<input id="data_nascimento" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('data_nascimento') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="data_nascimento" value="@if(!is_null(old('data_nascimento'))) {{old('data_nascimento')}} @else {{$usuario->data_nascimento->format('d/m/Y')}} @endif">
```

Comment: Show, esqueci de falar que existem casos onde data_nascimento será full, ai tá ocorrendo erro. Já dentro do controller, antes de gravar no banco eu tenho que fazer assim ```\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->data_nascimento)->format('Y-m-d')``` ou teria outra forma?

Comment: Para gravar na BD tu é que sabes o formato que te dá jeito, eu guardo com o tipo default de laravel, que é `Y-m-d H:i:s`, https://ideone.com/b4M8DF